# HTML email background breaking layout in Outlook - using vml method

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Currently using http://backgrounds.cm method for background email generation. When not using the code, the email looks correct in most test. When the background image is added, Outlook 2013 will display it, but all the table formating expands to 100%. Not sure if I'm implementing it incorrectly.

Currently applying the background to the topmost table which contains several cells, not the entire body.

I've pasted the code here: http://pastebin.com/dX8zEZDV

Answer (score 2):

I did a couple things to fix it:

- Changed your doctype from `strict` to `transitional`.
- Removed duplicate meta tags.
- Closed all unclosed-tags (`img` and `br` tags).
- Removed your outer two containing tables (`#container_table` and `#container_wrapper`).
- In `#container_table`, removed `min-width`, added `margin:0 auto` and `align="center"` so table is centered.
- In VML code section, replaced `mso-width-percent:1000` to `width:850px`.
- Updated closing VML tags to correct nesting order (closed prematurely).

Optional:

- In VML code section, changed the color to better match your background (#292929).

The only instance I've found where VML background images and the inline fallbacks don't work is when I view my Outlook email using the Gmail app on Android. However, when I view my name@gmail.com email in the same app, it's fine. So in the event the background image doesn't load, the bgcolor will display so your users can still see your white text.

Note:
Always remember to validate your code. Even if there are some errors you can't fix (for instance the `background` attribute in the `td` won't validate), you can verify all your tags (minus any VML code) are nested/closed properly, as well as finding any accidental special characters you may have copied into your code from Photoshop or Word.

Updated source at jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WebDevJoshB/32mzg5fb/)

Comment: +1. Regarding the _accidental special characters_, use https://detergent.io to clean and encode the text before pasting into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If *table formatting expands to 100%*, it's because you set "Table cell width" setting to "Full email width". It's best to use VML background images on fixed width and height table cells.

Ideal settings for backgrounds.cm are "A single table cell" and set `width` and `height`. Otherwise, the result might look different from non-Outlook clients (sometimes it's still OK if it's agreed upfront with stakeholders).